# Node modules cache in deployment of angular cli app

Tags: angular, deployment, node-modules

I am using Jenkins for deployment, now on every deployment I need to clone the app and run `npm install` every time.

Is there any way to cache or something so that data downloading should be save.

I am asking this for Angular CLI app on a ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following issue was resolved with making a symbolic link to node_modules outside the directory.

So it doesn't make installation again of node modules.